# How to get FFmpeg to consistently apply speed effect to first few frames?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264

I am using FFmpeg to apply speed effects to short gifs and videos and I noticed strange stuttering on looping gifs when sped up. I manually tested and found what was going on. FFmpeg failed to apply the speed filter to the first few frames of the video.

I started with this file, which loops between the numbers "1 2 3 4" every frame.

[123410fps.mp4](https://puu.sh/H6ZPC/7696473e5f.mp4)

I then ran the command `ffmpeg -i 123410fps.mp4 -vf setpts=0.5*PTS 123410fpsout.mp4`

That left me with this file: [123410fpsout.mp4](https://puu.sh/H6ZQF/92d00af623.mp4)

On close analysis, I discovered that the output file didn't show a repeating `1 3 1 3` or `2 4 2 4` pattern, but shows `1 2 3 4 1 3 1 3 1 3...` the speed effect **didn't apply for the first few frames**

I apologize if it sounds like i'm being super nitpicky, but my usage for this is on very short gifs and videos where this effect is very apparent. **How can I prevent this effect from happening and have a 100% consistent speed effect applied to the video?** I don't mind using other non-ffmpeg software but a CLI solution that works easily for most videos is ideal.

In case anyone is wondering, I don't use ffmpeg to encode gifs, i use [gifski](https://gif.ski/) from ffmpeg exported image sequences. The problem shows up even when no gifs are used, so it's not a gifski problem.

Comment: Why does your `123410fps.mp4` video have an audio stream? The FFmpeg wiki in its [How to speed up/slow down a video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) page says "Note that in the following examples, the audio stream is not changed, so it should ideally be disabled with -an", but you are not disabling it in your command. Is the output the same when you disable the audio?

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón it has an audio stream because I made and exported it from premiere pro with default settings.
Also in my actual implementation I apply the correct speed filter to audio and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `fps` filter after the `setpts` filter and use the `-t` option like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 123410fps.mp4 -vf 'setpts=0.5*PTS,fps=10' -t 1.64 -an 123410fpsout.mp4
```

`10` is the fps of your `123410fps.mp4` video and `1.64` is the half of its duration in seconds.

[The documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) says this about the `fps` filter:

> Convert the video to specified constant frame rate by duplicating or dropping frames as necessary.

It seems that the use of this filter forces a correct dropping of frames.

The [Changing the frame rate page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) of the FFmpeg wiki describes how to use the `fps` filter, but also says this:

> The output duration of the video will stay the same.

The `-t` option is necessary to obtain an output with half of the duration of the input, which is consistent with the speed up of 2x.

The `fps` filter also has a `round` parameter that in this particular case allows you to obtain an output with the numbers 1,3,1,... or 2,4,2,...

For 1,3,1,... you can use `fps=fps=10:round=up`.

For 2,4,2,... you can use `fps=fps=10:round=down`.

Comment: Here is my resulting file: [123410fpsout.mp4](https://puu.sh/H7jIR/9060e29003.mp4)

The first frames are interpreted correctly, but the video is the same length as the original IF the video is sped up. If the video is slowed down, it works correctly.

Also I had to change the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @melody_florum, you are right. I edited the answer to include the `-t` option to limit the duration of the output.